# sql server 2008 how do i make an exact copy of a database on the same server?

Tags: sql-server-2008

i need make an exact copy of a database on the same server. is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Backup and restore it under a different name.  Or install a named instance and backup from the DEFAULT instance and restore to the named instance under the same name.

Comment: And don't use the Database Copy Wizard, because it's a piece of junk that fails 90% of the time.

Comment: @Phoebus - I don't know if I'd go that far, it has its uses, but doing it this way is generally quicker anyway.

Comment: @farseeker: phoebus is never wrong

Comment: @I__ - in that case, we have a paradox...

Comment: @Farseeker Yeah, I just always seem to end up frustrated when I try to use it;)  @I__ I appreciate the vote of confidence!

Comment: @farseeker i suggest you take your paradox to the dentist